# want to know DATE FORMAT of Yammer API for passing query parameter as date in URL

Tags: yammer

I found these links on this site itself..
GET https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/users/{USER_ID}/modified_before/{DATETIME}.json?access_token={ACCESS_TOKEN}

GET https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/subscriptions/created_after/{DATETIME}.json?access_token={ACCESS_TOKEN}

I want to know which date format do i need to use to run my URL properly.
Any kind of help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I can't find an example of the requests you've listed. The only example I've found online was someone asking if it was possible to do that with the Yammer API, and the answer appears to be no.

Take a look at the Yammer Ruby gem for example, there is no option as you've described: https://github.com/yammer/yam/blob/master/lib/yammer/api/user.rb

So it's not a matter of having the right timestamp format, it's that the API doesn't support what you're trying to do.